# How to pass function parameters from Aurelia view to controller?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm creating a web application using Aurelia. (http://aurelia.io/).
I need to pass function parameters from HTML view to controller. Here's my HTML code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Full Name</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr repeat.for="user of users">
      <td>
        ${user.fullname}
        <div id="${user.oid}" class="collapse">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#${user.oid}" click.delegate="select($user)" data-toggle="collapse"
           class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

In this code, you can see this function with parameter of '$user'.

> click.delegate="select($user)"

I need to access this user object from the controller as I have done in the controller. But it's not working and get me undefined error.

```
select(user) {
 console.log(user);
}
```

When I print the user object, it's undefined. So can you tell me how to fix this please ? If I can't pass the whole user object, tell me a way to pass one single value like 'user.fullname'. That would also be fine.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following Change:

```
click.delegate="select(user)"
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will do that :)